# Can't pop3 from exchange server after a reboot

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook

Last night I shutdown my Exchange 2003 Virtual Machine, I added a new VHD (For backups), and booted it again.  Now I can't POP3 email from it with Outlook 2007.
In Outlook I get the error:
Task 'blake@MyDomain.com - Receiving' reported error (0x800CCC0F) : 'The connection to the server was interrupted.  If this problem continues, contact your server administrator or Internet service provider (ISP).'
Does anybody know what is wrong?  All I did was a reboot.  I haven't formated the added disk.  There are no weird errors in the event log.
I can still send mail with Outlook over port 25.
I can send and recieve mail with OWA.
I can POP3 the mail to my phone (it take about 15 minutes after sending a message, but I do get it eventually).
EDIT:
The 'Microsoft Exchange POP3' Service says that it is started but if I stop it and try to start it again, it fails saying 'Could not start the Microsoft Exchange POP3 service on Local Computer.  Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.'
I did some googling and someone on [exchangefreaks.com](http://www.exchangefreaks.com/pop3-server-will-not-restart-start-t142854.html) said that if I use task manager to 'End Task' on inetinfo.exe, then I can start the POP3 service fine.
Does anyone know what causes this problem?  I am fine for now since I did get the Service started, but If it does this after every reboot...

Comment: To be honest, the Outlook error doesn't help too much. What would have been potentially useful: a manual POP session using `telnet`. If I were you, I'd schedule another reboot window, and test to see if this does actually happen every time or if it was just a one-off.

Comment: I did try to telnet in following the instructions at http://www.theitguyrox.com/2010/02/26/telnet-to-test-pop3 . I just got a blank box. That is what pointed me toward restarting the POP3 service. What I don't fully understand is how my blackberry could pop3 from the server even though Outlook and telnet failed.

Comment: Either the BlackBerry isn't really POPping the mail (is there a BES server involved?) or the POP server likely would have responded to the `telnet` test _eventually_. In any case, I hope this is a one-off and not a regular event for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem - on restart of the server pop service is not available. What I do is I start it manually in Exchange System Manager ( Servers -> {Your server name } - Protocols -> POP -> default ) right click and choose start from popup

Not sure how to make the virtual pop server start automaticaly